# How to remove namespace prefix. (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, default

I have an XElement, resulting from a transform that looks like the following.

```
<src:Person xmlns:src="http://www.palantir.za">
  <src:Name>Jenifer Harvey</src:Name>
  <src:BirthDate>1969-11-13</src:BirthDate>
  <src:IdentityNumber>6906678550017</src:IdentityNumber>
  <src:Sex>Male</src:Sex>
</src:Person>
```

I would like to transform this XElement into a new XElement that has 'src' as a default namespace rather than a 'named' namespace as above.

I realise they are probably semantically identical, I just want to maintain consistency in what is being stored.

I want the following.

```
<Person xmlns="http://www.palantir.za">
        <Name>Jenifer Harvey</Name>
        <BirthDate>1969-11-13</BirthDate>
        <IdentityNumber>6906678550017</IdentityNumber>
        <Sex>Male</Sex>
</Person>
```

Thanks

Regards

Craig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the `xmlns:src` attribute and add a new `xmlns` attribute:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(
        "<src:Person xmlns:src=\"http://www.palantir.za\">" +
        "  <src:Name>Jenifer Harvey</src:Name>" +
        "  <src:BirthDate>1969-11-13</src:BirthDate>" +
        "  <src:IdentityNumber>6906678550017</src:IdentityNumber>" +
        "  <src:Sex>Male</src:Sex>" +
        "</src:Person>");

xdoc.Root.Add(new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.palantir.za"));
xdoc.Root.Attributes(XNamespace.Xmlns + "scr").Remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, the simple solution just didn't occur to me... :-o

Comment: Hi. what if the xml is having namespace prefixed attributes?How to remove the namespace prefix in the attribute eg: <src:Sex des:profession="student">Male</src:Sex>